# Trigger python script through a button

Tags: custom-button

I have a python script that extract the Account data into a dataframe then do some calculation, dump the new data into an another dataframe and push it into the Salesforce.

I would like to trigger all of above automatically through a button.

I am aware that this link: [How to create custom buttons](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10368/how-to-create-custom-buttons) will let me create a button but then how can i execute the python from it? Do i need to write JS which executes the python?

Is there any preferred solution other then this?

Answer (score 3):

The short (albeit not entirely correct) answer is that you cannot run Python in a browser (and thus, you cannot run python from a button click).

Generally speaking, the only language that can be run in a browser is Javascript. There are a few things like [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) (a pyhton-to-Javascript transpiler) that could help, but you're really trying to force a square peg through a round hole here.

Trying to use Python is just introducing unnecessary complexity. Surely you can accomplish whatever it is that your Python script is trying to do with Javascript.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you might even be better off using a combination of Apex and Javascript, or perhaps you don't need to write code at all and can use one of the declarative tools that Salesforce offers (such as workflow or process builder)

Answer (score -1):

You need to expose the python script at an API on your local host server and then create a button on salesforce where you can post the URL of the API and the button should run your python script when clicked.